# Background cover while page resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My page has some animations that sometimes change the page height (on purpose), so initialy when the page is loaded and page height is 100%, the background image covers the page. 
But when it runs the animations, the page height can go beyond 100%. The only way to effectively cover all the background is to change background height from auto to a bigger value (e.g. 200%), but doing so i am also changing the page height. In other words, is it possible to cover (dynamically) the page when the animations are running while keeping page height at 100% when animations are not running?

my css code for the background:

```
background: url(background2.jpg)repeat 5% 5%;
position: absolute;
background-size:cover;
top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
z-index: 400;
height: auto;
width: auto;
```

Comment: `overflow: hidden` will avoid other elements to alter the page height.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var isAnimating = $("#someid").is(':animated'); 
    //will return true if selected element animating
    if(isAnimating == true){
        $('#div').css('height','value');
    }
    else{
        $('#div').css('height','value');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    background: url('') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);/* For IE8 and earlier */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
```

hi friends apply this css